# Flutter app segfault on startup (release mode only)

Tags: android, flutter, segmentation-fault, crash, release

my app crashes (only in release mode) as soon as I start it.
It seems to be a segfault (thanks to logcat, see attached logs) but i haven't touched to any of the native code so I'm not sure where could it come from, and how to debug that...

Here is my `flutter doctor -v`:

```
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.7, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19045.3570], locale fr-FR) • Flutter version 3.13.7 on channel stable at C:\Users\Me\Documents\Code\SDK\flutter • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git • Framework revision 2f708eb (9 days ago), 2023-10-09 09:58:08 -0500 • Engine revision a794cf2681 • Dart version 3.1.3 • DevTools version 2.25.0
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.4)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.7.34031.279
X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these components:
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
- If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
C++ CMake tools for Windows
Windows 10 SDK

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3)
• IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.74.0

[√] Connected device (5 available)
• M2012K11AG (mobile) • 192.168.178.28:39079 • android-arm64 • Android 13 (API 33)
• POCOPHONE F1 (mobile) • 192.168.178.29:5555 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64 • Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19045.3570]
• Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 117.0.5938.152
• Edge (web) • edge • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 115.0.1901.203

[√] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

And here is the logcat output:

```
10-18 14:51:50.663  2485  2485 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-18 14:51:50.663  2485  2485 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/beryllium/beryllium:10/QKQ1.190828.002/V11.0.9.0.QEJMIXM:user/release-keys'
10-18 14:51:50.663  2485  2485 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
10-18 14:51:50.663  2485  2485 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2023-10-18 14:51:50+0200
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   : pid: 2454, tid: 2454, name: fr.circleshare  >>> fr.circleshare <<<
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   : uid: 10757
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x86
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000007e  x2  0000000000000000  x3  0000007fd8b418a8
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :     x4  0000007fd8b418ac  x5  0000007e63068a39  x6  0000800000000000  x7  2e33774b04ff3a60
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :     x8  00000000a298c000  x9  19bf5d8f6296c9d7  x10 0000007fd8b418a4  x11 0000007e63f7d1dc
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000007e63f7d224  x13 0000007e63f7d26c  x14 0000007e63f7d2cc  x15 0000000000000000
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000007fd8b418a8  x17 0000000000000000  x18 0000007eeaf1c000  x19 0000007e65069c00
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :     x20 0000000000000000  x21 0000007fd8b418a8  x22 000000000000007e  x23 00000000d8b42080
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000007e64413000  x25 0000007ee9d5f020  x26 0000000000000043  x27 0000007ee9d5f020
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000000000000043  x29 0000007fd8b41830
10-18 14:51:50.664  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :     sp  0000007fd8b417b0  lr  0000007e64209c98  pc  0000007e64209c9c
10-18 14:51:50.686  2357  2357 D EventBus: [2357, u0] send(AppTransitionFinishedEvent)
10-18 14:51:50.687  2357  2357 D EventBus: [2357, u0]  -> ForcedResizableInfoActivityController [0x445d9f1, P1] onBusEvent(AppTransitionFinishedEvent)
10-18 14:51:50.687  2357  2357 D EventBus: [2357, u0] onBusEvent(AppTransitionFinishedEvent) duration: 14 microseconds, avg: 179
10-18 14:51:50.687  2357  2357 D EventBus: [2357, u0] send(AppTransitionFinishedEvent)
10-18 14:51:50.687  2357  2357 D EventBus: [2357, u0]  -> ForcedResizableInfoActivityController [0x445d9f1, P1] onBusEvent(AppTransitionFinishedEvent)
10-18 14:51:50.687  2357  2357 D EventBus: [2357, u0] onBusEvent(AppTransitionFinishedEvent) duration: 5 microseconds, avg: 178
10-18 14:51:50.688  2107  2135 I Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_stopped time:15346760
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 00000000003c2c9c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::GetStringChars(_JNIEnv*, _jstring*, unsigned char*)+620) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 0000000000156b84  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_content_XmlBlock_nativeGetAttributeIndex(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, _jstring*, _jstring*)+72) (BuildId: 1d7baea5f024f2014e5eeed6dece8fa6)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0000000000a3aef0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+208) (BuildId: 875c0b6fad51c97f190b23a8bb6697e1afa7c768)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 0000000001229bcc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getAttributeValue+60) (BuildId: 875c0b6fad51c97f190b23a8bb6697e1afa7c768)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 0000000000136334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 0000000000144fec  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 00000000002e27cc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+384) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 00000000002dda2c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+892) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 00000000005a1540  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+980) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 0000000000130a14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 00000000000cc93e  /data/app/fr.circleshare-k-paSNkK8J6kbbwrqx1Big==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (androidx.core.content.g.h+38)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 00000000005a2af8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1040) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 0000000000130994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 00000000000cc8a6  /data/app/fr.circleshare-k-paSNkK8J6kbbwrqx1Big==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (androidx.core.content.g.e+22)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 00000000005a2af8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1040) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 0000000000130994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 00000000000ccd0e  /data/app/fr.circleshare-k-paSNkK8J6kbbwrqx1Big==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (androidx.core.content.g.attachInfo+62)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 00000000002b3ae0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.17460956533834400288+240) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 00000000005912f0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 000000000013f468  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #20 pc 0000000000cb7168  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider+1752) (BuildId: 875c0b6fad51c97f190b23a8bb6697e1afa7c768)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #21 pc 0000000000cb6918  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders+280) (BuildId: 875c0b6fad51c97f190b23a8bb6697e1afa7c768)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #22 pc 0000000000cafa38  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication+7192) (BuildId: 875c0b6fad51c97f190b23a8bb6697e1afa7c768)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #23 pc 0000000000ca412c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+7420) (BuildId: 875c0b6fad51c97f190b23a8bb6697e1afa7c768)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #24 pc 000000000166f9a4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+180) (BuildId: 875c0b6fad51c97f190b23a8bb6697e1afa7c768)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #25 pc 0000000001678e04  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1540) (BuildId: 875c0b6fad51c97f190b23a8bb6697e1afa7c768)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #26 pc 0000000000cb87a4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+756) (BuildId: 875c0b6fad51c97f190b23a8bb6697e1afa7c768)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #27 pc 00000000001365b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #28 pc 000000000014500c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+276) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #29 pc 00000000004afcf4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #30 pc 00000000004b1898  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1480) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #31 pc 000000000043cc3c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #32 pc 00000000006d4b34  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+180) (BuildId: 178682794d896aa0861e6b421cbfbee013eb0917)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #33 pc 00000000022e32d8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+136) (BuildId: 875c0b6fad51c97f190b23a8bb6697e1afa7c768)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #34 pc 0000000002303a54  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2100) (BuildId: 875c0b6fad51c97f190b23a8bb6697e1afa7c768)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #35 pc 00000000001365b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #36 pc 000000000014500c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+276) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #37 pc 00000000004afcf4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #38 pc 00000000004af8e4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+408) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #39 pc 00000000003ba680  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+624) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #40 pc 00000000000c09ec  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+116) (BuildId: 1d7baea5f024f2014e5eeed6dece8fa6)
10-18 14:51:51.077  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #41 pc 00000000000c39b0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+944) (BuildId: 1d7baea5f024f2014e5eeed6dece8fa6)
10-18 14:51:51.078  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #42 pc 00000000000035bc  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1388) (BuildId: 48163b9f3f369f4e0e105e516c26f543)
10-18 14:51:51.078  2485  2485 F DEBUG   :       #43 pc 000000000006ebc4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108) (BuildId: f6cc5d2d702265511937b56460b37693)
10-18 14:51:51.238  2485  2485 E crash_dump64: cannot open libmiuindbg.so: No such file or directory
10-18 14:51:51.239  1368  1368 E /system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
```

The app is also quite huge, and has many packages. I updated them all, did a clean + get, but the issue persists.

Could someone help me with this please? It's completely blocking me from releasing it...
I've tried with the 2 different Android devices listed above, but same results.

Comment: Hey, Have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Is this with android gradle plugin 8+?
Try downgrading or settings `android.enableR8.fullMode=false` in gradle.properties